# How can I properly escape bash variables when being quoted in various ways

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, sh, command-line-arguments

I have the following code:

```
set -o xtrace
openDirectory ()
{
    lxterminal --command="zsh -c 'cd "$1"; zsh -i' "
}

# Handle argument.
if [ "$@" ]
then
  openDirectory ~/Projects/Clients/"@1"
  cd $1
fi
```

This fails if there is a space in the argument passed.

```
lxterminal '--command=zsh -c '\''cd /home/chris/Projects/Clients/Test' - 'Space; zsh -i'\'' '
cd Test - Space
cd: too many arguments
```

How can I properly escape this? Is this even feasible to be done with something like bash?

Comment: why just not use the `--working-directory` argument for the `lxterminal`, instead of the  `cd` + escaping hell? e.g. `lxterminal --working-directory "$1" --command="zsh -i"`

Comment: Thank you for the workaround!

Comment: I think you mean `$1` instead of `@1`. The correct way to check if any arguments are passed, though is to use `if [ $# -gt  0 ]; `. `"$@"` will expand to multiple arguments, which may cause `[` to fail.

Comment: bash, or zsh? The details differ.

Comment: The actual script is run with bash, but I end up in a ZSH prompt or that is the goal. If I understand things correctly.

And yes the @1 is probably a typo, not sure why it appeared to be cd'ing into the right directory though (just with spaces).

Comment: By the way -- does `lxterminal` change from the working directory it's started in? If not, `(cd "$1" && exec lxterminal --command="zsh -i")` is another option (just as efficient, because the `exec` cancels out the performance cost of the subshell created by `()`, while allowing that subshell to scope the `cd`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the enclosing shell really is bash (as the question is tagged), you can use `printf -v varname %q "$var"` to store a safely quoted instance of the value of `var` into the variable named `varname`, as such:

```
openDirectory()
{
    local cd_cmd cmd
    printf -v cd_cmd '%q ' cd "$1"
    printf -v cmd '%q ' zsh -c "$cd_cmd && zsh -i"
    lxterminal --command="$cmd"
}
```

`printf '%q'` evaluates to a version of the given string which will, when `eval`'ed by bash (or any shell with equivalent semantics), evaluate to the original literal value.

To explain *why* this is done that way:

- In the above, all quote characters included in the code itself are syntactic rather than literal: We're depending on `printf %q` for *all* quoting and escaping. This is a best-practice approach: Using literal quotes means that literals inside the data being generated are able to escape those quotes.
- Running shell directives such as `&&` through shell quoting will make them into literal data. Thus, we *want* the `&&` to be literal data rather than syntax when we're passing it as an argument to `-c`, but not literal data when handled by the remote shell -- this is why it's only present in the *last* quoting pass.

Comment: Just a note that `openDirecty() "~"` will not have `~` expanded to the user's home directory. `openDirectory ~` has to be specified instead.

Comment: Correct. Quoting is per-character, so you can write `openDirectory ~/"some name with spaces"`.

Answer (score 2):

Even though a good suggestion was made in the comments, as a general way to deal with such issues you could write it this way :

```
set -o xtrace
openDirectory ()
{
    local safe_path
    printf -v safe_path "%q" "$1"
    lxterminal --command="zsh -c 'cd $safe_path; zsh -i' "
}
```

For a better way to prepare the command to be passed as argument to `lxterminal`, please see CharlesDuffy's answer.

As for the rest of your code, I would probably use the following :

```
# Handle argument.
if
  [ -d  "$1" ]
then
  openDirectory ~/Projects/Clients/"@1"
  cd "$1"
fi
```

Using `"$@"` as the if condition could yield 0 (true) and execute the body if argument 1 exists but is empty (null string), but a following argument is not.  I I assume this is not what you want.

I am unsure if "@1" is a typo or if it really is intended to mean a directory named "@1" inside your "Projects/Clients" directory.  But the `"$1"` argument to `cd` should be quoted, for sure.

Comment: You aren't properly quoting the parameter expansion anymore. It should be `--command="zsh -c 'cd \"$1\"; zsh -i'"`.

Comment: @chepner Not too sure why I missed this, probably was too focused on adding the missing quotes and left everything as is.  Thanks.

Comment: This is buggy -- security-holes-level buggy -- as is. What if your directory name passed in `$1` contains `$(rm -rf ~)`? That'll get expanded in double quotes. Or `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` -- that way it'll still get expanded if you replace the double quotes with single ones.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added a directory existence check.  Could a valid directory name contain a risky string?  I would tend to think it could, and this is not enough.  Would a solution using `printf -v X "%q"` first be the right solution?

Comment: While POSIX doesn't *require* names outside the Portable Filename Character Set to be supported, most filesystems allow directory entries to have any name that contains neither `/` or NUL -- and a *path* can of course contain `/`s, if the attacker controls the name of at least some parents to the directory your maliciously-named entry is placed in. Yes, using `printf %q` is the Right Thing.

Comment: If you're quoting with `printf %q`, then you don't want to inject additional quotes on top; the string that generates is intended to be ready-to-use.

Comment: ...well, hmm. I'm not *completely* certain about all the interactions around single-quotes present in the literal name -- not needing to think about those kind of interactions to figure out how they could work is part of why I'm using `printf %q` for *both* quoting stages in my own answer, vs just one of them. But it's at least not obvious that this is exploitable, vs previously where it was obviously exploitable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help.  By the way, my understanding is that the security risk comes from `lxterminal` potential handling of the argument passed, not the original shell's (or `zsh`'s) handling of the said argument.  Is that right?

Comment: it's not lxterminal itself, but the shell invoked by lxterminal to run the command it was passed; zsh is only *after* that. So you'll have lxterminal run (probably) `sh -c` with the next argument being the string with your `zsh -c` command.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I do not know `lxterminal` at all, let alone how it handles external commands passed as arguments, so really not obvious to me.